# Не получается выбрать ListViewItem из Expander

Tags: wpf, listview, xaml, grid

Главное окно приложения разделено на Grid-ы, в одном из которых находится ListView для выбора контента (Page) в другом. ListViewItem, находящиеся просто во ListView, можно навести и выбрать, при этом подгружается необходимая мне страница (PageClient.xaml). А вот ListViewItem из Expander-а невозможно выбрать, только навести, поэтому PageCategory.xaml подгрузить я не могу. Подскажите, пожалуйста
, как решить эту проблему.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0 0 0 0"  Background="#06061d" >
<ListView x:Name="GridMenu" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" FontSize="18">

<ListViewItem Height="50" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
<ListViewItem.Tag>
<Frame Name="frame2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="PageClient.xaml" />
</ListViewItem.Tag>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0">
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Account" Width="20" Height="20" Foreground="#FFF08033" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Text="Клиенты" Margin="10"/>
 </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>

<Expander Background="#06061d" MinHeight="40" Width="264">
<Expander.Header>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-20,0,0,0">
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Information" Width="20" Height="20" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="10 0 0 0" Text="Справочники" Height="20"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
<StackPanel Background="#06061d" >
<ListViewItem Height="40" Padding="0">
<ListViewItem.Tag>
<Frame Name="frame3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="PageCategory.xaml" />
</ListViewItem.Tag>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="34 0">
<TextBlock Text="Категории" Margin="10"/>
</StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
</Expander>
</ListView>
</StackPanel>
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=GridMenu, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Если вам нужна иерархическая структура – используйте TreeView. И имейте ввиду, что все элементы, которые не являются `ListViewItem` будут обернуты в него, т.е. ваш `Expander` окажется внутри `ListViewItem`, соответственно выбрать, сделать текущим можно только этот внешний `ListViewItem` и пихать `ListViewItem` куда-то глубже просто не имеет смысла. Ну и вообще ваш подход отличается от общепринятого и нерационален. Почитайте про DataTemplate и пользуйтесь им.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, просто полностью переписывать красивую оболочку меню под TreeView уже нет времени.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена созданием нескольких ListView вместо одного и переопределением контента ContentControl в коде с помощью прописаний события ListViewItem_Selected для каждого элемента.